# Free Android scientific calculator that can convert *to* fractions

Tags: gratis, android, calculator

I've tested ~20 or so free calculators from the Play store but still have not found what I was looking for...

Requirements:

- Runs on Android 5
- Calculations are done offline
- Free (ad-supported is ok, but ad-free preferred)
- Should not require any ROMs from real calculators (so [Andie Graph](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.supware.tipro) is not an option, although the TI-63 can fulfill all those requirements)
- Can calculate trigonometric functions in Degrees
- Has a calculator-like keypad, i. e. I don't have to type s,i,n on a QUERTY keyboard to get `sin`.
- Can convert results to fractions (if they can be converted, of course)
- Bonus if this also works for fractions of square roots (if not, I can square myself and convert to fractions)
- Acceptable precision (i. e. does not trip over its own feet when trying to convert to fraction because of precision loss before)
- Bonus if it can graph functions, show the input formula in mathematical notation, or detect more things in the results automatically (e. g. prime factors, cube roots).

The best calculators (in my opinion) so far are [Desmos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desmos.calculator) and [HandyCalc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mmin.handycalc), but neither can display results in fractions in all cases...

Test expressions (yes each of them fails even in the decimal expansion on some of the tested calculators):

- `22 / 7 * 7 - 22` = 0
- `sin (60)^2` = 3/4
- [`tan(atan(1)-2*atan(1/4))`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(atan(1)-2*atan(1%2F4))) = 7/23

Answer (score 1):

[WolframAlpha Pro](https://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/) and its [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wolfram.android.alpha&hl=en) should be able to do everything you request and more. Though input may be a bit confusing at first (using a qwerty keyboard for inputting most things, with an extended, in-app keyboard for non-standard symbols) it can solve/graph/give you important points, such as intercepts and symmetry, about nearly any equation.

Comment: Not exactly free, and does not support offline calculation (does it?)

Answer (score 0):

Found one: [CalcTastic Scientific Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shaytasticsoftware.calctasticfree) can do this very well (for denominators < 1_000_000)

Answer (score -3):

Try [Calculator++](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.solovyev.android.calculator) - it is free and powerful.
Also I like to use [WolframAlpha](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wolfram.android.alpha), for too complicated cases.

Comment: did not find an option to show result as fractions in Calculator++

Comment: yeah, I've forgotten to mention that

Comment: @MikhailK. Please take a screenshot showing a result fraction and add it to your answer.